# Show output on terminal and output to log file, without using tee

Tags: terminal, osx, output

I want to run a command, then show the output on the screen as well as output it to a log file, currently I use `tee -a`, but the problem is `tee` doesn't preserve colours, and currently I have not been able to find a way to do that.

Comment: `tee` doesn't do anything to color. Probably your source command *(like `src_cmd | tee ...`)* omits color escapes when writing to anything other than a terminal. If so, there is usually a switch that can `--force-color` or something for the `src_cmd`, or else you can `luit -olog logfile src_cmd` wrap your `src_cmd` in a Pty that also logs its output to another file.

Comment: @mikeserv Alright, the source command is `brew`, but it's page man page doesn't say anything about colours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tee` doesn't know anything about colors. But some applications produce colored output only when their output goes to a terminal, not when it goes to a regular file or to a pipe. In such cases, check if the application can be told to produce colored output anyway. For example, under OSX, for `ls`, you need to set the environment variable `CLICOLOR_FORCE`.

If an application behaves differently when its output is a terminal and can't be configured, then run it in a terminal. The [`script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/script.1.html) utility runs a command in a terminal and records the output, escape sequences, screen redraws and all.

```
script -q brew.log brew …
```

(But doesn't brew keep logs already? Maybe if you set `HOMEBREW_LOGS`?)

Comment: Is there any way to create the file with `script`? I output it to a different file every time, and also, what does `-c` do? It's not on my BSD.

Comment: Another problem I am having with `script` (I am not familiar with it since now) is that even if I create the log file ahead, I still can't output it there since I get a "Permission denied" error. It's not a problem with the actual script file nor the output folder because if I replace `script` with something random like `>  "$D/brew_update $num"` (same folder), it works.

Comment: @DisplayName Sorry, I'd used the Linux syntax instead of the BSD syntax. I don't understand what you mean about creating a file. `script brew.log …` creates `brew.log`.

Comment: The errors were because of using the GNU syntax. Thanks.